# Banned from the chat for a strange reason

Tags: support, chat

Here is what happened (I suspect it might be a bug, and I'd like it not happen again):

> your account has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for 29 minutes.

For those who have appropriate privileges, here is the link to the message:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/6503237/history

It says:

> Stéphane **said** (9:48 PM): Perso, j'ai adopté ⊆ pour l'inclusion large, ⊂ pour l'inclusion stricte et je slape tout individu qui fait autrement.
>
> Stack Exchange **deleted** this message (9:57 PM)

In this message *slape* was a Frenchified *slap*. As far as I know, even in English, neither *slap* or *slape* could be considered foul language?

Why was this message considered inappropriate? Was it an automatic decision? A human mistake? A bug?

Comment: We're on it. I don't see anything inappropriate there, but I can't figure out what happened. Are you unbanned already? I can't find any applicable button in your chat profile.

Comment: @Giles: I'm unbanned (but the 29 minutes have elapsed anyway).

Comment: @Gilles It's under "moderation tools". The "suspend this user" section is replaced with an unsuspend button during the suspension time.

Comment: @downvoter: care to give some reason at least?

Comment: Human error, shit happens. How mystical you may have perceived it at that moment, once one knows about flagging in chat, "suspended for posting inappropriate content" seems pretty clear. [Imho](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=imho), and I vote with mho, that's not interesting. I did [give a shot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806530/git-creates-huge-temporary-garbage-objects) at such now-stupid questions (no offense meant), but I'm oh so very tempted to delete it (the bonus "Disciplined" badge makes the temptation unbearable, so here basically I'm helping you leave it :P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see any more information than you, except that there has been one offensive flag on this message. I can't see who cast the flag or who marked it as valid. The validated flag caused an automatic 30 min suspension.

I don't see any inappropriate content in your message. So, whoever flagged this and whoever marked it as valid: please don't do it again. (Mods may not be able to tell who you are, but Stack Exchange staff certainly can!)

Sorry about that. Don't hesitate to ping a moderator on Meta if it happens again.

Answer (score 3):

According to our technical overlords, I am guilty of the flagging, and thus of the ban. I swear I have not done this intentionally and I humbly apologize for the disagreement it caused.

Seriously, I don't have a clue on how I flagged this. I will offer a sacrifice to the god of technical issues in order to prevent any future occurrence of this.

Comment: You were probably trying to answer my message at the time. Maybe the UI could be improved a little bit to prevent almighty users to accidentally cast bans. Anyway thanks for telling this, I was pretty much confused at understanding what had happened.